# Action Helper by name EntityManger not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server

Just started building an app with the zend framework. I've working on a zend server 5.5. When I try to open the first controller I created, I get the following error message:

```
Application Error
Message: Action Helper by name EntityManager not found

Stack trace:
#0 c:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php(293): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::_loadHelper('EntityManager')
...
```

My guess is that I'm missing a library, but I'm not sure which one. Anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you register the Helper? 
Do you register the helper in the Boostrap or in the application.ini?

Where is the helper located? Please try to give more information concering that.

Anyways, it looks like you are using a standard setup, so you have to register the /path/to/your/helper with the Action Helper Broker.

For indepth information check the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.broker)

Comment: It was in the boostrap file but it looks like i had it commented out. It's been one of those days. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the class name of your helper file. The name must be something like this:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_helperfilename
```

This had worked for me.